# How to create a circular gradient using either of aggdraw or PySDL2?

Tags: python, sdl-2, python-imaging-library, pysdl2, aggdraw

## The Problem Generally

I need to create a circular gradient of arbitrary radius and map it to the current mouse position. The project is primarily using [OpenGL](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/) & [PySDL2](https://pysdl2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), but, for legacy reasons, also uses [aggdraw](http://www.effbot.org/zone/aggdraw-index.htm) (with [Pillow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/) wrapping PIL). Broadly, SDL2 runs interactions with OpenGL & most UI stuff, but aggdraw does, predictably, the drawing.

I've written a *very* rudimentary function. It works except that the latency between mouse motion and the gradient draw grows dramatically with gradient radius (see my code; it's obvious why).

The code below uses aggdraw; aggdraw objects are elsewhere converted into byte arrays with [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) to pass to OpenGL.

I'm open to solutions that use the SDL2 drawing library, but I've never used it and would appreciate being treated like the nub I am for such solutions. ;)

---

**Notes for the Specific Context**

Since the code I've provided is so sparse, as a courtesy I should mention that this interfaces with a large module I've been writing for ~1yr ([KLIBS](https://github.com/jmwmulle/klibs)). Said module primarily does a lot that's impertinent here, but, the below function *does* plug into lot of in-house code. Alas, I've yet to write documentation for the module because it's (currently) for a local context.

This function *is*, verbatim, my code however; and the rest of the library has been well tested; the overhead is <10ms from anything else going on.

I think it must be possible to do this faster than the screen refresh rate, there *is*  a latency tolerance of ~30ms (project's context is graduate work in the cognitive science of vision). I know this also depends on hardware; generally, we're talking iMacs no older than 3 years.

I'm sure this can be done much better, but I am waaay out of my depth; I usually work with with web languages (javascript/PHP/html/css)!

```
def mouse_gradient(radius):
        mp = mouse_pos()  # custom function, just wraps fetching mouse coords from sdl2
        mouse_grad = None
        mouse_grad = aggdraw.Draw('RGBA', (radius, radius), (0, 0, 0, 0))
        for n in range(radius):
            n = float(n)
            r = float(radius - n)
            opacity = int(( 0.25 * n / radius) * 100)
            brush = aggdraw.Brush((255, 0, 0), int(opacity))
            tl = (radius - r) // 2  # ie. top-left
            br = (radius - r) // 2 + r  # ie. bottom-right
            mouse_grad.ellipse((tl, tl, br, br), brush)

        return mouse_grad  # where it is subsequently blit to the screen
```

Comment: Can you determine the bottleneck of your function? Is it the runtime of aggdraw (which, with all the mapping through Pillow and numpy sounds heavy-weight)? Or are you passing in a larger radius, making the for loop long-running?

You may want to have a look at the `sdl2.sdlgfx` module, which allows you to draw AA circles to SDL textures, which may speed everything up by bypassing the Pillow and numpy conversions.

Comment: That is a handy suggestion that is well outside my current knowledge-base; I'll explore and post if/when I am able to make use of this suggestion.